# Examples of interventions changing the Population distribution of a system

Tags: distributions, self-study, dataset

When learning about the Datasets of naturally occuring systems you encounter distributions, for example power law distributions in the domain of population sizes of cities.

In my understanding this usually reflects a simple functionality of the system you are sampling.(domain specific that means lots of cities form in small sizes and the likelihood of them getting increasingly bigger decreases exponentially). This is accordingly reflected in the simulations of those systems. Sticking to that domain example political influences on population sizes usually only change the behaviour by ,for example a constant factor(omitting taxes to promote a certain growth), or change behaviour at one end of the spectrum (charging additional taxes to second homes in big cities).

Are there examples of interventions in systems that completely change the distribution to another? (for example power law to Erlang distribution, or vice versa) I don't have a specific domain in mind but I wanted to know if that happens at all.

I try to establish a simulation framework, and asked myself the question of what changes to the system can occur. As distributions often determine which statistical values are significant (averages do not tell a sufficient story when describing power law distributions) I wanted to know if I have to expect distributions to change in a system due to an intervention.

Comment: This question sort of answers itself insofar as it's a tautology: you make your *family* of distributions large enough to model the phenomena of interest.  Could you therefore explain what it means to you for a distribution to "change"? For instance, if its center or scale change (which is contemplated in many models, such as ordinary least squares regression), would you view that as a "change" of distribution?  What if the shape changes, as happens in most generalized linear models?  And if you accept changes of shape as inconsequential, then exactly *what* would be a real "change"??

Comment: I try to follow the comment. A distribution has not really anything to do with scale but rather if I can extract meaningful information from statistical values. In a normal distribution I can infer a lot of information when I compare a Datapoint to for example the mean of all values. Then I can use this information to infer information about my datapoint. However if a system can be changed and repopulated in a way that my distribution changes (no longer normal distribution, instead you now expect an Erlang distribution f.e.). I want to know if there are known examples where this can happen